# QWidget over another widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

I have graphs (QCustomPlot) that are arranged vertically with a separator (QSplitter).

How can I get the window as in the picture when I click on the right button? I know how to handle the right button signal, but I can not understand how to display the window I need.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a QMenu as a member of your widget. In .h:

```
#include <QMenu>
#include <QAction>
.....
QMenu menu;
```

In constructor:

```
QAction* action=new QAction("save",this);
connect(action,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(save()));
menu.addAction(action);
QAction* action2=new QAction("clear",this);
connect(action2,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(clear()));
menu.addAction(action2);
setContextMenu(&menu);
```

Comment: Wow! Exactly what is needed. Thank you! However, I did not understand what the last function `setContextMenu(&menu);`  is for, and I do not. I'm putting it this way `menu.exec(event->globalPos());`.

Comment: This function sets a context menu for this widget, so it can be called by clicking a right mouse button.